# Spring Boot with custom UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data, spring-boot

What is the correct way to add my custom implementation of UserDetailsService (which uses Spring Data JPA) to Spring Boot app?

```java
public class DatabaseUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Inject
    private UserAccountService userAccountService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userAccountService.getUserByEmail(username);
        return new MyUserDetails(user);
    }

}


public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

    public User findByEmail(String email);

}



@Service
public class UserAccountService {

    @Inject
    protected UserRepository userRepository;

    public User getUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.sample")
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.sample" })
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    ...

    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }


    }

    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 10)
    protected static class AuthenticationSecurity extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Inject
        private UserAccountService userAccountService;

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        }

        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new DatabaseUserDetailsService();
        }

    }

}


@Entity
public class User extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();

    // getter, setter

}


@Entity
public class Role extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String authority;

    // getter, setter

}
```

I cannot start app beacouse I get (full exception here http://pastebin.com/gM804mvQ)

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.sample.model.User.roles[com.sample.model.Role]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1134)
```

When I configure my `ApplicationSecurity` with `auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery("...).authoritiesByUsernameQuery("...")` everything is working including JPA and Spring Data repositories.

Comment: The problem is the JPA mapping. Please add the User and Role entities(classes).

Comment: Entities added. Anyway, I don't think entities are problem because JPA is working fine without my UserDetailsService.

Comment: Nevertheless I think Evgeni is right. The error is a mapping error. Maybe you can share a complete project?

Comment: @DaveSyer, I tried to minimise it here https://github.com/igo/spring-boot-userdetails. Still not able to run however I got another exception NPE - UserAccountService in DatabaseUserDetailsService is null. Please try, you might know how to use custom UserDetailsService :)

Comment: Your app seems to work for me (once I added @Configuration to the AuthenticationSecurity). How do I break it?

Comment: Hi @DaveSyer, i want to build same application with angular, can you give any good reference for it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your app seems to work for me (once I added `@Configuration` to the `AuthenticationSecurity`). Here's another working sample of a simple app with JPA `UserDetailsService` in case it helps: https://github.com/scratches/jpa-method-security-sample

Comment: Thanks, that helped to move forward. But now I get `o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.sample.model.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session`. Yet I did not find any examples which load also roles with lazy fetching. I updated my github sample.

Comment: Lazy roles sound like a bad idea (you always need to check the authorization after authentication), but that just looks like you don't have a transaction.  Maybe the `UserDetailsService` boils be transactional *and* load the roles, killing two birds with one stone, as it were?

Comment: @DaveSyer Hello, I can't get what you mean. I have the same error as the OP (`failed to lazily initialize a collection of role`). Should I have to add `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` to `com.sample.model.User.roles` or is there a less heavy way? Thank you!

Comment: Ideally you should not use JPA for user details. If you must then fetch the roles inside the `UserDetailsService` (and make it transactional).

Answer (score 4):

You can also follow [this blog](http://www.ekiras.com/2016/04/authenticate-user-with-custom-user-details-service-in-spring-security.html) to implement custom user details service.

This example shows how you can send bean to userdetails service for injection.

1. Autowire the Repository in the WebSecurityConfigurer
2. Send this bean as a parameter to the user details service by a parameterized constructor.
3. assign this a private member and use to load users from database.